# Cross-domain tracking through analytics + adwords

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

We currently have 2 domains: domain1.com and domain2.com. Both domains receive traffic from a single google adwords account. We would like to see all of the analytics  for both domains (including adwords impressions, click, cost, etc). Previously, domain1.com, had analytics setup and was pulling the adwords just fine. I followed google's guide to cross-domain tracking here (http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55503) and it seems to be tracking everything just fine except adwords. In the adwords section I am only seeing visits, while impressions/clicks/cost/ctr/cpc are all zero. Any idea what I'm doing wrong / missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up the profiles with the option to pull data from the same AdWords account then you should see duplicate data in both of them. One possible problem you might have if you've only just set up the new profile is that it can take up to 24 hours before the AdWords data is imported.

Comment: Thank you Ewan, that was exactly the problem. For whatever reason it took a little longer than 24 hours, but now everything is perfectly synchronized and showing up as expected. Thanks again, cheers!